# Document Set Contents Not Displaying With Custom Branding

Tags: 2013, page-layout, document-set, design-manager

I have a simple masterpage based off of the Oslo theme & the Starter Master Pages kit (https://startermasterpages.codeplex.com).

We have a site with a Document Set library and while the list showing the document sets is displayed correctly, the contents of the document set aren't.

The page shows the default document set 'header' with the icon, document set name and description and the view and edit text links. My test data has 7 documents uploaded however they are not shown in the usual 'document set contents' panel.

Using the IE developer tools, I can see that a JS variable is populated with their data (in the page source) - much as it is with the OOTB themes.

Am I missing something on the Page Layout to display the Document Set Contents? I only have the 'Page Content' Content Field in there which I thought would be enough...

Thanks!

**Edit:** I've also noticed the following javascript error:

*SCRIPT5007: Unable to set value of the property 'innerHTML': object is null or undefined*
`document.getElementById("idParentFolderName").innerHTML=...`

Comment: Seems that you have not provisioned the list view web part on the new welcome page!

Comment: ... I think you may be on to something! I noticed that in the Design Manager the same problem was happening (static page content was shown but the list items were not). Looking in to that now.

Thanks for the pointer, if you want to expand your comment in to an answer I'll accept that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that the list view webpart is missing from your welcomepage. SharePoint has a specific webpart for showing the document set content, the content of the .dwp that is used when provisioning OOTB is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<WebPart xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2">
    <Assembly>Microsoft.Office.DocumentManagement, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c</Assembly>
    <TypeName>Microsoft.Office.Server.WebControls.DocumentSetContentsWebPart</TypeName>
    <Title>$Resources:dlccore,DocSetContentWP_Title</Title>
    <Description>$Resources:dlccore,DocSetContentWP_Description</Description>
    <PartImageLarge>/_layouts/15/images/msimagel.gif</PartImageLarge>
    <DisplayText></DisplayText>
</WebPart>
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is already answered, but maybe this will help someone in the future.

If you have a custom master page, it is very likely that the Document Set list view is already there, it just isn't being rendered due to wrong Place Holder positioning within the master page.

If you temporarily switch back to seattle.master, the list view will become visible.

The fix is:

- Make sure PlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea is included in the master page and it is NOT being hidden through the `Visible="false"` attribute (maybe using `<div style='display:none'>` instead)
- Make sure PlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea is placed **before** PlaceHolderMain within the master page

More [here](http://www.eliostruyf.com/document-set-view-not-visible-in-sharepoint-2013/)

Comment: that moment when you search for something and find your own answer.    -_-

Answer (score -1):

This can be fixed by adding to your HTML masterpage such block. You can hide it with css.

```
<!--SPM:<SharePoint:AjaxDelta id="DeltaPlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea" runat="server">-->
<!--SPM:<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea" runat="server">-->
<!--SPM:</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>-->
<!--SPM:</SharePoint:AjaxDelta>-->
```

Source: http://blog.drisgill.com/2012/12/design-manager-bug-sharepoint-2013-rtm.html

Comment: I don't think this answer pertains to the question.

Comment: No seems more related to the "Add an app" problem