# Document set documents not showing in custom masterpage

Tags: 2013, custom, branding, document-set

I'm branding a subsite, with two document libraries that can contain document set. I started designing the document libraries with oslo masterpage applied to the subsite, and it worked correctly (still it does). Then I started to make some branding work, converting a HTML file into a masterpage and aplying it to the subsite. Everything worked right, except for the view of document set content. The default view for the library only shows the document sets, and this is the spected way. But when I go into a document set, I can see document set properties at the top of the page, but the document list is missing.

I've tried editing the page, and the webparts seems to be correct ("Document Set Properties" at the top holder, and "Document Set Content" at the central holder). Also, deleting the webparts and put them into again, the properties webpart works, but the content one doesn't.

I've found [THIS POST](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/67630/document-set-contents-not-displaying-with-custom-branding) but it didn't helped (tried to substitute the XML definition of the webpart in docsethomepage.aspx in SP Designer with no success)

The HTML code generated by SP seems to be correct, as I can see the name of the files if I search for them in "view page code" browser option.

I don't know where to look for help, hope someone birng some light. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, find something interesting. It looks like there is a bug in SharePoint while converting custom HTML to masterpage. The process "forgets" to include two placeholders that seems to be necessary for the masterpage to work. I added code for insert DeltaPlaceHolderLeftNavBar and DeltaPlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea in my custom masterpage and it worked.

The solution was found [here](http://blog.drisgill.com/2012/12/design-manager-bug-sharepoint-2013-rtm.html). Not the same problem, but it looked like it could work... and it did :-)

EDIT: just making some proofs... if you don't need navigation and title placeholder, simply put them into a div with *style=visibility: hidden;* It still works and don't show.